# How to make internal transfer between two journal odoo14

Tags: accounting, odoo-14

In v13, we can choose internal transfer and then fill destination_journal_id and make transfer.In v14, how to make transfer between two journal.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Bashir. Check this link https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-make-internal-transfer-in-odoo14-182575